# Forcing an iframe to refresh when using laravel response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel, iframe

I'm making an application and it has a section where it reads from a directory, grabs the next file and allows you to manipulate it.

My page has 2 sections, 1 section is details on the current file, and the other section is a preview of the file. Each time my page refreshes it grabs the next single document from the directory specified and displays it as an iframe so the user can preview it, but i'm having trouble with the iframe refresh.

When the page reloads, it shows the text and name of the next file like its supposed to do, but the preview still shows the file i've just processed until i force refresh the page a good few times and wait.

I've tried a lot of different methods to force load the iframe, but none seem to be displaying it smoothly.

PHP

```
  public function displayFilePreview($id){
    $selectedQuarter = self::getSelectedQuarter($id);
    $files = self::getFiles($id);
    //This line just grabs the directory of the next file
    $nextFile = $files[0];
    return response()->file(storage_path('app/'.$nextFile, "Cache-Control: 
    no-cache"));
   }
```

HTML

```
<iframe id="file-processing-file-preview" src = "/fileProcess/displayFile/{{$selectedQuarter->id}}" width='400' height='300'></iframe>
```

Javascript

```
$('#file-processing-file-preview')[0].contentWindow.location.reload(true);
```

How do i get it so that no matter how quickly I cycle through the files in my directory, the iframe will always show the current selected file instead of caching and taking manual force refreshes and time before it shows the right file?

Comment: Sounds like this would work smoother using ajax. In a json response you would send what is needed for the preview as well as the next file url to update the iframe `src` with

Answer (score 1):

Figured out a simple solution.

In the page I am loading the iFrame in, I simple attached the current date and time to the end of the iFrame to force it to see it as a new request.

From

```
 <iframe id="file-processing-file-preview" src = "/fileProcess/displayFile/{{$selectedQuarter->id}}" width='400' height='300'></iframe>
```

To

```
 <iframe id="file-processing-file-preview" src = "/fileProcess/displayFile/{{$selectedQuarter->id}}?time={{date('Y-m-d H:i:s')}}" width='400' height='300'></iframe>
```

Refreshes perfectly every time now